# design wordpress plugin with css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I wrote a small plugin and i want to add some css design my plugin meta boxes in the WordPress system.
All the scripts of adding a css file to WordPress plugin that I found are referring to including a css file in the plugin output page on the website itself. - wp_enqueue_scripts

the solution i created is to use this piece of code in my plugin page:

```
echo '<style type="text/css">';
include( '/css/style.css' );
echo '</style>';
```

But if feels to me like an unprofessional solution so I wanted to ask if anyone knows a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_enqueue_style()` yourself, with [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url):

```
function my_styles(){
    $css_path = plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__);
    wp_enqueue_style('my_stylesheet', $css_path);
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_styles' );
```